# I can not get data from jQuery muscles

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am learning tutorial, but I understand that the author made a mistake / mistakes.
The data is sent via GET in php and write, but do not turn back.

JavaScript:

```js
    function loadAllPost() {
        var divs  = $("#posts");

        $.get("twitor.php?action=last", function() {
            var posts = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                var newPost = addNewPost(posts[i].name, posts[i].text, posts[i].date);
                posts.push(newPost);
            }
            divs.children().remove();
            divs.append(posts);
        });

    }


    $(function() {
        loadAllPost();
        setInterval(loadAllPost, 5000);
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var newPostName = $("#name").val();
            var newPostText = $("#text").val();
            var newPostDate = (new Date()).toLocaleString();
            var newPost = addNewPost(newPostName, newPostText, newPostDate);
            newPost.hide();
            $("#posts").append(newPost);
            newPost.slideToggle();

            $("name").val("");
            $("text").val("");

            $.post("twitor.php?action=new", {
                text: newPostText,
                name: newPostName
            });
        });
    });
```

Ie like php sends data, but does not have JS embeds them in HTML.

PHP:

```php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'new') {
    addNewPost();
}
elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'last') {
    getLastPosts();
}

function getPDO(){
    $db_host = "****";
    $db_name = "****";
    $db_user = "****";
    $db_pass = "****";
    $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
    //$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    return $PDO;
}

function addNewPost(){
    $params = [];
    $params['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $params['text'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $PDO = getPDO();
    $Statement = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(`name`, `text`, `date`) VALUES (:name, :text, NOW());");
    $Statement->execute($params);
}

function getLastPosts() {
    $PDO = getPDO();
    $Statement = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15");
    if(!$Statement) return;
    $posts = $Statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($posts);
}
```

Comment: Test changing if ($_GET['action'] == 'new') for if ($_POST['action'] == 'new')

Comment: Not work! In Jquery useds string -   $.get("twitor.php?action=last", function() {

Comment: can try this `$.get("twitor.php?action=last", function(data) {var posts = data; `